# JSON request limits

Tags: php, json

I've recently been having trouble with a website when trying to make JSON requests in PHP. A few days ago the requests began to hang and I haven't been able to load the data since.

I've tried the same code on another website and it worked fine. Is it possible the website I'm getting the data from has banned me after too many calls? If so, is there a way to a prevent this from happening again on another website in the future?

Comment: Simply ask for the owner to remove ban/whitelist you? Unless you're doing it without their permission. In that case, I can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would state as the comments say. The owner of the website must have banned you. It could happen if you make too much call in a short amount of time, or if you disrespect the rule of the api ( I'm presuming you are doing those JSON requests to an API of some sort ).

So in short, if you want to be able to reuse the service, you have to send a nice e-mail to the owner, asking why you have been banned, and what you can do to be un-banned.